# php sql query changes url, however doesn't change data

Tags: php, sql, max

I'm trying to make a "next button" for my database, so i can view one image at a time. However  the way i have it right now only changes the url and not actually the image [check it out here.](http://goawaymom.com/images.php?imagecount=84) It sticks to the image with the highest id on it (87) no matter what the url is. How do i fix this?

this is how my db looks

[image]

```
<?php 
require("includes/conn.php");

if (isset($_GET["imagecount"]))
$next = (int)$_GET["imagecount"]; //int is for sql injection 
else
    $next = 0;

$result = mysql_query("select * from people order by id desc limit $next, 1") or die(mysql_error());


?>



        <?php


            $result = mysql_query("select * from people order by id desc limit 0, 1 ") or die ("haznot DB: " . mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

                echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
            }

        ?>

<a href="images.php?imagecount=<?php echo $next+1; ?>">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `WHERE id = $next` in your query. Not what you have.

Why do you have two mysql queries...

```
"Select * FROM people WHERE `id` = $next"
```

Comment: so what i must do instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

You should select `WHERE id=$next`. You seem to have fewer than 87 images present, so the limit clause won't behave as you expect.